# Change my MX record on my server to google MX?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, mx-record

I got a windows server 2008 where I host a site, now I decided to have the email on google apps. I did add the MX records I get from them to my DNS settings on the server but with no luck. I recently started doing server stuff so I did like this.

Server Manager / Roles / DNS Server / DNS / SERVERNAME / MYDOMAIN / Forward Lookup / New MX

Host or child domain: What goes here?
FQDN: here is my domain name, i think because I named the ns my domain?
FQDN MX: here is the google MX record I got from them
MSP: 10

I have no Idea where I go wrong but I thought I would ask you guys if any of you can maybe give me some tips on what to look for or any newbee mistake I do that you see from this little info.

I really appreciate all help I could get on this.

Comment: See: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the host or child domain blank - it will then apply to the parent domain (what you refer to as MYDOMAIN). FQDN will autofill with MYDOMAIN - leave it as is. FQDN MX should be the hostname that Google provided you and then assign the appropriate number. Create one such MX record for each entry they asked you to add.

Comment: What I did before was I put www.domain.com on FQDN. Hope that is the issue. I did like you said now but have to wait 48 hours for google to verify it. I will get back and post here if it don't work